# Cancelling a timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a problem with a timer in my logger class. I created my own logger which should be as simple as it is possible - user can only call static log() method. Every call log() method causes that a log object (message, time, additional information) is adding to a list of logs.
When user calls this method **first time**, logger also starts a new Timer which saves all logs from a list to a file every 30seconds.

However, I don't have any idea where to call timer.cancel() method. I don't want to force user to do this in his code. Is it necessary to always cancel timer? Or this method is just to stop when user wants it.

Comment: Why don't u use Androids logging mechanism? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: I need log my messages to a file but android.util.Log doesn't support it (correct my opinion if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you do not need shutdown hook at all in this case. When VM is closed, all the threads will be cancelled anyway, and all open files will be closed, so no worries.

I believe what you want is to avoid the task waking continuously every 30 s even if app is not doing anything. I propose to do it a bit differently:

Whenever you log something in log method:

- store log entry
- check if you have a timer task waiting to be executed (one boolean volatile 'taskRunning' flag). If not - fire task with 30 seconds delay, but only ONCE (not repetitive) and set the taskRunning flag to true. If flag is set to true - do nothing.
- in your timer task: clear the 'taskRunning' flag, write all the logs stored so far and ... do not fire another task. No need. Whenever someone writes log file, it will start another task which will write logs 30 secs after.

Note. In order to avoid races you need some synchronisation on log read/write as well.

Comment: Thanks - it's good solution and I will try to use it in my project. But firstly, I have one question - will the timer thread be created every time (after fire new task) or just once after start timer? I guess only once, but I want to be sure.

Comment: You are right. All the tasks are executed within one thread which is created when you start the timer.

Comment: I used your solution in my project and it works. However, one thing isn't still clear. If application will close in normal way (or close unexpectedly) will this thread be stopped and cleaned too? Or should I cancel it myself? I could cancel timer in onDestroy() method but i don't want to force user to do that. Secondly - what if application stops, while timer thread saves logs? Thread will be stopped in the middle of work or save all?

Comment: Good to hear. For thread cloasing it's again the same story - when application is closed, all the threads are closed and open files too. The process (virtual machine) in android is actually closed very rarely - usually when you kill application with (For example) Advanced Task Killer, Force-Close on Exception or when there is not enough memory to load another application. In such case application is killed "forcefully" - i.e process is killed.... And thread are killed along the way. If it so happens that thread is writing at this moment - it will be killed in the middle of the work.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that the best way in this unexpected situations is to flush all logs in onLowMemory() method (it will be helpful when OS will kill application) and add Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() to have opportunity to write logs before application will close after unhandled exception.

Comment: Yep. If you really, really want to make the best to write all logs, this is the way to go.. Actually - you might want to consider another option - You might keep the log file open and write the logs to it directly. The slowest part of writing to the file is to open it, and if you keep it open, you could handle writing to the file log directly rather than keeping it in memory (especially if you make some reasonable-size buffer for it). The worst you can loose is the buffer (make flush() periodically - more often than every 30 sec). And you save a lot on Garbage Collection in this case!

Comment: Thanks, both solutions are satisfying. I will consider which one is better for my application.

Answer (score 1):

A shutdown hook is the way. Read the caveats, and description [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29). Also consider [this](http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/) for a prewritten log to file for android solution

Comment: I read about microlog a few days ago, but I would like to write logs to file in new thread (not one by one but several at once). I'm not sure, but when I was using microlog probably write logs to file in the same thread.